# @keyframes doesn't support Arabic

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations, keyframe

I try to write a sentence in Arabic with @keyframes but @keyframes doesn't support the Arabic language and comes out with unintelligible characters

```css
.caption { background-color: black; }

.caption h1::after {
  animation: move 3s infinite;
  content: "";
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff !important;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    content: "م"
  }
  10% {
    content: "مر"
  }
  20% {
    content: "مرح"
  }
  30% {
    content: "مرحب"
  }
  100% {
    content: "مرحباً"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="caption">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Letters and symbols similar to =-&++#@

Comment: I tried converting your code to a live snippet, but then I can't reproduce what you describe. Can you confirm or infirm you do experience the issue here as well, and if so, what browser you are using, otherwise, try editing the snippet until it does reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have tried, everything that works well and Arabic works all over the site but @keyframes don't work at all in Arabic .. I use chrome and vscode

Comment: The code snippet seems to work fine here. (Chrome/Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Arabic include the attributes `dir="rtl"` and `lang="ar"` on tag elements with Arabic characters:

```
h1::after {
  content: "مرح";
}
```

**Example 1:**

```
<h1>Testing Arabic</h1>
```

This render incorrectly characters (on Chrome it seems to work, but in Safari and Firefox don't).

[image]

**Example 2:**

```
<h1 dir="rtl" lang="ar">Testing Arabic</h1>
```

This render correctly!

[image]

Also, you can read more about problems animating the "content" property here: https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/

Also you can include inside yours `<head></head>` tags `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: Thank you, still doesn't work in Firefox anyway I will try again

Comment: Try to add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` inside your `<head>` tags ;)