# How to write a different language in CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I want to write a text in Arabic in the place of content in CSS, but it shows different characters in place of the real text, when I type it in HTML it works fine because I've set meta charset to UTF-8,I checked [@keyframes doesn't support Arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405734/keyframes-doesnt-support-arabic) but it didnt work with Chrome, what should I do in CSS to make it show real text..

```
@keyframes lang{20% {content:'سلام';font-size: 450px;} }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@keyframes doesn't support Arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405734/keyframes-doesnt-support-arabic)

Comment: Have you tried using `@charset "utf-8";` (or other real charset you use) at the beginning of the CSS file? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset)